# error when creating an auto increment primary key column on heroku postgres

Tags: postgresql, heroku-postgres

Trying to set up my postgres table in heroku and I'm getting this error when trying to set up the auto-incrmenting in the primary key on my table

`user_id_seq relation does not exist`

This is the create statement

```
CREATE TABLE "public"."user" (
    "id" INTEGER DEFAULT nextval('user_id_seq'::regclass) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    "uname" CHARACTER VARYING( 255 ) COLLATE "pg_catalog"."default" UNIQUE,
    "description" CHARACTER VARYING( 2044 ) COLLATE "pg_catalog"."default",
    "country" CHARACTER( 3 ) COLLATE "pg_catalog"."default" DEFAULT 'USA'::bpchar NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY ( "id" )
, CONSTRAINT "unique_uname" UNIQUE( "uname" ) );
```

What does that error mean and do I have to set up that relation beforehand somehow?

Comment: Have you created the sequence?

Comment: new to postgres - how do I create the sequence? I was assuming that the sequence was automatically created for an auto-incrementing field, does it have to be set up manually?

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL

Comment: how did you do insert in this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to [**create the equence**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-createsequence.html) first with something like:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE user_id_seq
  INCREMENT 1
  MINVALUE 1
  MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807
  START 1
  CACHE 1;`
```

Or declaring you column `id` as a [**serial**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-numeric.html):

```
CREATE TABLE "public"."user" (
    "id" bigserial NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    "uname" CHARACTER VARYING( 255 ) COLLATE "pg_catalog"."default" UNIQUE,
    "description" CHARACTER VARYING( 2044 ) COLLATE "pg_catalog"."default",
    "country" CHARACTER( 3 ) COLLATE "pg_catalog"."default" DEFAULT     'USA'::bpchar NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY ( "id" )
, CONSTRAINT "unique_uname" UNIQUE( "uname" ) );
```

which is equivalent to:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE user_id_seq;

CREATE TABLE "public"."user" (
    "id" bigint NOT NULL UNIQUE DEFAULT nextval('user_id_seq'),
    "uname" CHARACTER VARYING( 255 ) COLLATE "pg_catalog"."default" UNIQUE,
    "description" CHARACTER VARYING( 2044 ) COLLATE "pg_catalog"."default",
    "country" CHARACTER( 3 ) COLLATE "pg_catalog"."default" DEFAULT     'USA'::bpchar NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY ( "id" )
, CONSTRAINT "unique_uname" UNIQUE( "uname" ) );


ALTER SEQUENCE user_id_seq OWNED BY public.user.id;
```